# Table View Add Functionality?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am new to the field of iOS development.

I have a tab bar application with four tabs, my second tab is a navigation controller which has a table on it when I press a cell it pushes to my detail view. My third tab is a favorite tab, and what I want is if I like anything in my table view how can I make that value go in the Favorite tab which might also have a table in it.

I want you ideas how can I do this ?

(Like should I have a button on the navigation bar "Add to Favourite" as soon as I click on that tab my table changes into edit mode with the "+" sign coming in front of every cell, the value I like I press the + sign and it goes in the favorite tab) this is what I thought but I really don't know how to implement it.

Can you help me out in this ?

Answer (score 0):

This question's way too big for Stack Overflow. You should really go through [Apple's sample code and documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).

To get you started:

- For the 4 tabs, you most likely want to embed everything in a [`UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which will be your root view controller.
- To get the edit mode functionality you're looking for, you're going to want to override `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to enable that. (See [`UITableViewDelegate` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).
- Using the edit mode "+" button functionality as a way to add cells to a favorites list is non intuitive. Your users are going to be used to seeing that button in the Contacts app, etc, in the context of being used to add more fields or more information. They're not going to expect it to put things in a list in a different tab. See how Apple manages favorites in the contacts app for an example of how to do it right. You should also consult the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: The first and second points are already sorted out, but the only functionality of how they manage the + green sign was what i was looking for.

Still Thank You for your reply

Comment: You mean how to detect when users use the green "+" button? You should implement `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view's delegate.

Comment: YES i want to know how the + green button comes in front of every table view cell, when i implement tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: normally the '-' red sign button comes in front of every cell

Comment: You have to override `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` to get it to show the "+" button instead of the "-" button. Read the `UITableViewDelegate` documentation I linked to. It's all there.